# msb4067 the element <State> beneath <Project> is unrecognized - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

We have just upgraded to Visual Studio 2017.  Our reports would preview in VS 2015, 2013 and 2010 but they will not preview in VS 2017.  We get this error message "msb4067 the element  beneath  is unrecognized" for any report we try to preview.
Has anyone else run into this and does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild 15.0 (Visual Studio 2017) throws error MSB4067 for solutions with SSDT projects (SSRS and SSAS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735390/msbuild-15-0-visual-studio-2017-throws-error-msb4067-for-solutions-with-ssdt-p)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a solution containing 11 SSRS projects. I found that disabling "Lightweight load" in the solution properties and then reloading the solution fixed the issue. Since making this change I haven't seen this issue again.

Comment: This worked for us. We have 30 or so SSRS projects and disabling lightweight loading allows us to build the projects now.

Comment: same... disabling lightweight solution load worked for us as well

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know the answer to this.  The only solution I have found to date is to uninstall and then reinstall VS 2017.  Very frustrating when it is occurring once a fortnight.

Comment: I think it's a compatibility issue between VS2017 and SSDT integration since they are two independent projects within devdiv. So far as I know, VS would probably recommend you to keep asking "Are we there yet?" at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data-platform/.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with Engineers from Microsoft I learned that the Lightweight Solution in Visual Studio 2017 does not work for report development yet.  We are no longer using the Lightweight solution and it works fine.